In reactjs and typescript: <HTMLDivElement> is not assignable to type 'string'
I am trying to add a class for my SearchContainer component and got some error as  below:
webpack compiled successfully
ERROR in src/components/Search/SearchForm.tsx:43:13
TS2322: Type 'IStyledComponent<"web",     FastOmit<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>,     never>>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
41 |         <SearchContainer>
42 |           <Form
> 43 |           className={SearchContainer}
   |             ^^^^^^^^^
44 |             submitButtonLabel={'Search'}
45 |             onBeforeSubmit={saveData}
46 |             formData={data}

This is how my SearchContainer look:
const SearchContainer = styled.div`
  max-width: 1024px;
  padding: 0 10px;
`;

Is there any workaround to solve this issue?

The 'workaround' is to use a string for the className as per the error message. It's not 100% clear what you're trying to do by passing a component as an HTML element class attribute, but if you want to use the same style on the form as a div, you either need to put the style in css and use class name, or make another styled.form with the same style applied.

I will move the style in css.
